# React only renders last element

Tags: arrays, reactjs, render

I'm creating a dialog where a grid is displayed with some content for a specific object (example bellow) and when console logging the data I received from the request I get the correct data:

```
0: {id: 1, workStationID: 200, version: '2.10', status: 'Fusion', dateTimeStamp: '2021-10-21T17:28:19', …}
1: {id: 1, workStationID: 31, version: '2.10', status: 'Fusion', dateTimeStamp: '2021-09-29T15:50:46', …}
2: {id: 1, workStationID: 21, version: '2.10', status: 'Fusion', dateTimeStamp: '2021-08-05T18:35:01', …}
```

However when the grid is displayed only the last element is rendered in the html and I can't understand why.

The code for the Component is the following

```
const PosListDetails = (props: PosListDetailsProps) => {
   
    const{onClose, openPOS, IP, store} = props;
    const classes = useStyles();
    const poslists = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.server.posLists);
    const loading = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.server.loading);
    const server = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.server.server);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const handleClose = () => {
        onClose();
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchPOS(IP, store));
    }, []);

    const columns: GridColDef[] = [
        { field: "col1", headerName: labels.pos(), width: 125 },
        { field: "col2", headerName: labels.ip(), width: 125 },
        { field: "col3", headerName: labels.version(), width: 125 },
        { field: "col4", headerName: labels.status(), width: 125 },
        { field: "col5", headerName: labels.timestamp(), width: 175 },
        { field: "col6", headerName: labels.hardware(), width: 200 },
        { field: "col7", headerName: labels.printer(), width: 125 },
    ]

    const rows = (): GridRowsProp => {
        return poslists.map(pos => ({
            id: pos.id,
            col1: pos.workStationID,
            col2: pos.ip,
            col3: pos.version,
            col4: pos.status,
            col5: pos.dateTimeStamp,
            col6: pos.hardware,
            col7:pos.printer,
        }));
    };


    return(
        <Dialog onClose={handleClose} open={openPOS} classes={{ paper: classes.paper }}>
             <DialogTitle >
                <Typography style={{ fontSize: 22 }} >
                    {labels.pos_list() + " - " + labels.store() + " " + server.loja}
                </Typography>
                <Typography style={{ fontSize: 15 }} >
                    {labels.ip() + " " + server.unifo2ip}
                </Typography>
                {onClose ? (
                    <IconButton style={{
                        position: 'absolute',
                        right: 8,
                        top: 8,
                    }}
                        aria-label="close"
                        onClick={handleClose}
                    >
                        <CloseIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                ) : null}
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent >
            <Grid item xs={12} style={{marginTop: "5px"}}>
                <TableContainer className={classes.tableContainer}>
                    <StyledDataGrid columns={columns} rows={rows()} loading={loading} />
                </TableContainer>
            </Grid>
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog >
    )

}

export default PosListDetails;
```

Comment: What is `StyledDataGrid`?

Comment: It's just a normal datagrid with some styled elements


`const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => createStyles({
    root: {
        "& .MuiDataGrid-columnsContainer": { color: theme.palette.primary.main },
        "& .MuiDataGrid-iconSeparator": { display: "none" },
        "& .MuiDataGrid-colCell, .MuiDataGrid-cell": { borderRight: "1px solid #f0f0f0" },
        
    }
}));

const StyledDataGrid = (props: DataGridProps) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return <DataGrid className={classes.root} {...props} />;
};`

Comment: @Manuel_dev did you ever find an answer to this? I'm having the same issue